# Problem with compiling/running a file in neovim

Tags: vimrc, neovim, filetype-c++

When I try to run a file with Neovim it shows me this:

[image: screenshot]

It doesn't allow me to type any input. How can I type some input using Neovim ?

This is my script for compiling:

```
g++ -static -DLOCAL -lm -s -x c++ -Wall -Wextra -O2 -std=c++17 -o $1 $1.cpp
```

This are my commands in Neovim for compiling and running a cpp file:

```
autocmd filetype cpp nnoremap <F9> :w <bar> !build.sh %:r <CR> 
autocmd filetype cpp nnoremap <F10> :!./%:r<CR>
```

Here is [my `init.vim`](https://pastebin.com/3LwP9PZ4).

I have windows 10 with WSL. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: You might like to read `:help :make`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run an external command using `:!` in NeoVim, it doesn't get connected to a terminal, which means it can't take input from the user.

From [`:help :!` in NeoVim](http://neovim.io/doc/user/various.html#:!):

> The command runs in a non-interactive shell connected to a pipe (not a terminal). Use `:terminal` to run an interactive shell connected to a terminal.

Note that this is NeoVim-specific. In regular Vim, running a command under `:!` runs in a terminal, which means it can take input from the user. This is intended behavior in NeoVim, it's that way by design.

Instead of `:!`, you can instead use the `:terminal` command to run your binary inside a NeoVim window.

For example, this command should take care of it:

```
autocmd filetype cpp nnoremap <silent> <buffer> <F10> :split | execute 'terminal ./%:r' | startinsert<CR>
```

I also added `<silent>` to the mapping, so that it doesn't print the Ex command before executing it (usually a good idea) and also `<buffer>`, since the mapping is set based on filetype, it should only apply to buffers of that specific filetype (and not be a global mapping, which would apply to all buffers and would potentially be overwritten by the mapping for the last filetype you opened.)

Comment: Thank you very much, sir !