# NeoVim - Interact with the thing that pop ups when you type in a command

Tags: neovim, command-line, terminal, external-command

### Questions

- How can I type something in there?
- What even is the name of this thing?

### Problem

If you type in for example

```
:!echo 'Hello World'
```

This kinda terminal thing pops up

I want to interact with it instead of it going away after the first key press. Example:

```
:!python3 -c 'input("Type a Number:")'
```

From the command above I get an Error.

I don't want to use the `:terminal` or any work arounds, I just want to know if this is possible^^

---

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: that's exactly the `:terminal` use case here

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt So it is not possible? Okay^^

Comment: I don't know if there are other ways to achieve this. I am merely telling you that you have found the `:terminal` use case here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a big difference between Vim and NeoVim when it comes to `:!`: the former runs the command in a shell-like environment, with stdin/stdout connected to the (p)TTY. The latter runs the subprocess in a "non-interactive" environment: essentially, no input is possible.

In both Vims you can use `:terminal` to have full interactivity; in NeoVim, this is the only builtin option.

Related: [1](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/31489/10604), [2](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/29318/10604).